# exporting DF to csv with variable file names

Tags: python, csv, file, variables

I would like to keep this same code but adjust the .to_csv section to save a variable repeating file name

```
for i in range(round(len(usersDf)/577)):
usersDf.loc[i*577:(i+1)*577,:].to_csv('Stored_files_'+str(i)+'.csv')
```

I would like the names of the exported files to look like this...I think I need some sort of loop?

Period 1 layer 1.csv

Period 1 layer 2.csv

Period 1 layer 3.csv

Period 1 layer 4.csv

Period 1 layer 5.csv

Period 2 layer 1.csv

Period 2 layer 2.csv

Period 2 layer 3.csv

Period 2 layer 4.csv

Period 2 layer 5.csv

Period 3 layer 1.csv

And so on....till the loop ends

Comment: Does each file name has just 5 layers?

Comment: yes its a total of 2460 csv files....
so it needs to be period 1-429, layer 1-5
and just keep going
1, 1
1, 2
1, 3
1, 4
1, 5
2, 1
2, 2
2, 3
2, 4
2, 5
3, 1
3, 2
3, 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
no_of_periods = 577
    no_of_layers = 5
    for i in range(no_of_periods):
        for j in range(no_of_layers):
            filename = f"Period {i+1} layer {j+1}.csv"
            #print(filename)
            usersDf.loc[i*577:(i+1)*577,:].to_csv(filename)
```

You can try this one out.